# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter get items as object list Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I would like to get all objects in my firebaseRecyclerAdapter as List.

Here is what I try ;

```
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("ABC").orderByChild("abc");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<myObject> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<myObject>()
                    .setQuery(query, myObject.class)
                    .build();

    adapterL = new myAdapter(options, MyActivity.this);

    ObservableSnapshotArray<myObject> mSnapshots=adapterL.getSnapshots();
    if(mSnapshots.size()!=0) {
      ...
    }
```

But always I am getting mSnapshots size 0. I thought, probably the firebase adapter not loaded yet, but I dont know.

So question; after query to firebase, how can I get the object list in firebase adapter ? Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use this:

```
snapshots.addChangeEventListener(object : ChangeEventListener {
    override fun onChildChanged(
            type: ChangeEventType,
            snapshot: DocumentSnapshot,
            newIndex: Int,
            oldIndex: Int
    ) {
        // An individual item has been changed
    }

    override fun onDataChanged() {
        // A full update has been received and processed.
        // Here's where you would use `snapshots` and process stuff
    }

    override fun onError(e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {}
})
```